# How to use getline in a loop c++

Tags: c++

I am using getline() in a loop. During the first loop everything runs okay except for the last getline(). During the second loop the first getline() seems to have been skipped. Here is the loop:

```
while(true)
    {
        cout <<endl<< "Enter Student's Name: ";
        getline(cin,tmp_name);
        cout << "Enter Student's RegNo: ";
        getline(cin,tmp_regno);
        cout << "Enter Student's marks: ";
        cin>>tmp_marks;
        mystudents.push_back(student(tmp_name,tmp_regno,tmp_marks));
        mystudents[no_ofStudents].getGrade();
        no_ofStudents++;
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Do you wish to continue? To continue enter yes or any other key to stop: ";
        getline(cin,continue_stop);
        if (continue_stop!="yes"&&continue_stop!="YES")
            break;
    }
```

Comment: what type is continue_stop?

Comment: Show all the relevant data types please!

Comment: These are the data types:                                              
int no_ofStudents=0;
    string tmp_name;
    int tmp_marks;
    string tmp_regno;
    vector<student>mystudents;

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> tmp_marks;
```

leaves the newline character ('\n') in the input stream. You have to figure out a way to read everything after that until the next newline.

Answer (score 1):

And another thing

```
if (continue_stop!="yes"&&continue_stop!="YES")
   break;
```

This will break `while` loop at wrong time.

Comment: this is not true, entering yes/YES breaks the loop

Comment: I am using YES or yes to allow user to either stop entering the data by exiting the loop or to continue entering the data

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> tmp_marks;
```

leaves `'\n'` in input stream and you are reading it in the next read

```
std::getline( std::cin,continue_stop);
```

You can ignore this character with:

```
    std::cin>>tmp_name;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"Do you wish to continue?";
    std::getline( std::cin,continue_stop);
    if (continue_stop!="yes"&&continue_stop!="YES")
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Try using this after cin

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what your code is doing and how it would help solve the author's original problem.

Comment: ` \n`  is the delimiter, the character after which cin should stop ignoring. Since the problem was running fine for the first loop but was ignoring the second getline always after the first loop, we have to try to take care of the cin as it always leaves `\n`  a new line in the input stream.